# Is this the right NPT male adapter for my needs?

Tags: plumbing, water

I recently purchased a Phyn Plus 2nd gen smart water leak detector. I arranged for a plumber to install it but the plumber hit a problem where some adapters were missing. The problem seems to be that the Phyn Plus has 1" NPSM male threaded ends, which may not be compatible with other pipes.

The plumber confirmed that I need a couple of: *SWP*4521010 LF Brass Straight Water Meter by Male Threaded Adapter, 1″ NPSM x 1″ NPT adapters. Phyn indicates they need to be manufactured by Uponor.

My problem is I can't find this item using the full code, starting with SWP. However, if I search just for 4521010, I quickly find this:

[image]

Notice the SKU starts with *LF* but the digits are the same. The title includes 1" NPT and it's from uponor, *but* it says 1" ProPEX instead of NPSM.

**My question is** - Is this part I'm looking for?

Comment: You're paying the plumber but he's not heading down to his favorite plumbing supply shop to pick up a specialty part that he doesn't have on the truck? Honestly, he's going to bill you for the part and mark it up to make a profit, if he's not interested in that, I'd consider a different plumber. Also, I wonder what's so special about the Uponor part that it _has_ to be that brand and none other...

Comment: I'm sure this is resolved by now, would you please write up an answer sharing what you did? Also, I'm surprised that I didn't also recommend that you ask your plumber if you'd found the right part. Of course, with my previous comment, I wouldn't put _that_ much faith into the guy...

Answer (score 1):

No it's not correct. The correct one seems to be hard to find. The one you're looking at is for pex which is plastic pipe. Your plumber requested 1″ NPT which is copper pipe thread not pex.

I ended up finding a 3/4" NPT to NPSM adapter. It restricts the line but it shouldn't really matter unless your house is very large.

3/4 in. NPT Brass Water Meter Coupling Complete with Gasket, 2-1/2 in. L with 1 in. NPSM

Comment: Is there something in the part number provided that tells you that the OP does _not_ have PEX plumbing? If so, please share that info ([edit] it into your answer) as it would be helpful to others. If not, how do you _know_ that a PEX fitting _won't_ work for the OP?

Comment: Yes his plumber requested 1″ NPT which is pipe thread on copper

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the Uponor part is a recommended/qualified part rather than a requirement. As MrPHP noted, the PEX adapter you found is the wrong part.

The key is that your Phyn device apparently uses 1" straight threading (NPSM or National Pipe Straight (threaded) Mechanical), which requires a rubber gasket inside the female fitting to make a seal against the face of the male fitting. Most plumbing (in the US at least) will have tapered rather than straight threading, allowing thread-to-thread sealing just by tightening, without a gasket. Thus, the other end of the adapter is spec'd as NPT (National Pipe Taper (threaded)).

Here is a generic adapter found on a shopify site to show what your plumber was recommending:

[image]